# IDE: ProjectManager expands allways its items

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

Delphi 2007:
I have a projectgroup with a couple of projects (bpl/dll/exe). Whenever I start the Delphi IDE some of the project entries are expanded and some are not. I would like to see all of them compressed after the start but I cannot see a way to do that.

Any hints?

Chris

Comment: possible duplicate of [IDE: Structure viewer displays all items expanded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164425/ide-structure-viewer-displays-all-items-expanded)

Comment: @RRUZ: Project manager is not the same as Structure viewer... I don't think it is duplicate, even if the answer is similar, which I don't know yet.

Comment: Definitely interested in the answer to this. Have occasionally run into this problem too ... and then it disappeared again without me knowing what caused the fix

Comment: I don't know an automatic way, but you can focus the project manager by <Ctrl+Alt+F11> and then use the usual VT shortcuts, e.g. <Home> then <Ctrl+Num-Divide> then <Left>. (Works in D2007.)

Answer (score 0):

When you load the IDE (or a Project/ProjectGroup) does it automatically reopen whatever units you had opened in the editor the last time you closed it? If so, then I believe that the Project Explorer will always auto-expand the tree to show all active units' represenative nodes in the tree.

Comment: Yes, I have the IDE configured, that the project desktop is restored but there is always a single project within the project group expanded initially. The good thing is that a setting of "Auto Collapse" within the Project Manager collapses that (unwanted) project and focus (and expand) a new selected unit.

So, I can live with that.

Anyway, thank you for your thoughts.

Christian