# IDE: Structure viewer displays all items expanded

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-2007

Delphi 2007:

Whenever I switch to a new pas file the structure viewer displays its class entries in an expanded form. This is very annoying!

Is there a way that the classes items are always displayed in a compressed tree view.

Chris

Comment: you can ask this question on http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right click on the "Structure" pane and select "Properties" from the context menu. In the "Explorer Options" dialog, you'll see a "Explorer categories" check list box. For each item in this box, there's a tiny figure (a tree) between the check box and the item name. For items you want to see contracted, click on this tiny figure. It will switch from an expanded tree to a contracted tree. Then select 'OK'.

Comment: Was looking for the such thing so long! This is the great example how NOT to design your GUI. I've never thought that this tiny image is a button!

Comment: @Linas - I think, I wasn't able to figure out that myself also. :) Luckily, the help button on the dialog provides the information. ;)

Comment: What me confused for a moment: Right clicking the "Structure" pane does not work when it shows the structure of a form. You have to switch to the code first, then the context menu shows the "Properties" item.